# FAILED: Error in metadata:

Tags: hive

when i am trying to show tables from hive databases the following error displays..
i granted permissions to ware house & Tables even though the error shows

hive> show tables;

FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error occurs when hive CLI is terminated improperly.

solution:

exit from hive,  give  'jps' command. some  process named runjar will be there.  kill it using ' kill -9 pid'

thats it. you are done.

plz ignore typo- replied from mobile